# Fine-tuning PyTorch: No deepcopy

Tags: pytorch, deep-copy

Regarding fine-tuning CNNs in PyTorch, as per [SAVING AND LOADING MODELS](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html):

> If you only plan to keep the best performing model (according to the acquired validation loss), … You must serialize best_model_state or use best_model_state = deepcopy(model.state_dict()) otherwise your best best_model_state will keep getting updated by the subsequent training iterations. As a result, the final model state will be the state of the overfitted model.

However, I have done something like this:

```
def train_model(model, ...):
       ...
       if validation_loss improves:
            delete previous best model
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), best_model_path)
       else:
             ....
        ...
        return model

 def test_model(model, best_model_path, ...):
     model.load_state_dict(torch.load(best_model_path))
     model.eval()
     ...

...

my_model = train_model(my_model, ...)

test_model(my_model, my_path, ...)
```

In other words, the model returned by the training phase is the final one which is likely to present overfitting (I did not use deepcopy). But since I saved the best model during training, I have no problem during the test/inference phase because I load the best model, overloading the final model obtained during testing.

Is something wrong with this solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You’re still following the tutorial’s instructions. Note this part of the tutorial:

> You must serialize `best_model_state` or use `best_model_state = deepcopy(model.state_dict())`

You serialized the best model’s state (wrote it to disk), so you don’t need to use `deepcopy`.

If you kept the model in memory, you’d use `deepcopy` to make sure it’s not altered during training. But because you’re keeping it on disk instead, it won’t be altered.

Comment: Thank you Arya. I just wanted to be sure that I have been doing it right and it seems it is ok according to your answer, since I overload the model with the best one during testing.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!